# Can RefluxJS stores indicate which property has changed when they call trigger()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux, refluxjs

I'm new to Flux as a whole, but I'm trying to get a grip on it by starting with Reflux, which seems a bit more opinionated and simpler to learn.

As I understand, Reflux stores have a `trigger` method which indicates the store's data has changed, and they pass the updated data into it. This data can then be set as a React component's state, (or as one of the state's properties) using the [Reflux.connect](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#using-refluxconnect) mixin or similar methods.

**But what if a store has multiple sets of data that need to be listened to separately?** Let's say I'm modifying the TodoMVC [RefluxJS example](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs-todo), and I wanted the TodoStore to also include a `title` property that indicated the name of the todo list (as well as the `list`, the list of TODO items). Lets say there is also a `<Title>` component that is listening for changes to the `title` property, and setting the `title` as its state when it does.

A call to `this.trigger(title)` would update the title component, but would also cause the todo component to try to use the title string as its state, so we need a way to indicate which data has been changed. Should these two properties (`title` and `list`) be separated into different stores? Or should all calls to `trigger` include a string that indicates the property: `this.trigger("title", this.title)` or `this.trigger("todos", this.list)`. Or should all the data be combined into one object which is then picked by the listeners (e.g. using `Reflux.connectFilter`)?

```
this.trigger("todos", {
    todos: this.list,
    title: this.title
});
```

These last two examples introduce new data to the `this.trigger()` call, meaning that `Reflux.connect` can't be used any more, because `connect` takes the data returned from a store and directly sets the components state to it. Does this mean we have to use `Reflux.listenTo(TodoStore,"onTodoChange")`, and then filter out the `trigger` calls that aren't relevant to this component?

Answer (score 2):

(1) Its very important stores broadcast data change event to the subscribed top level view components.(The so-called controller views, as explained in http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html).

(2) The re-usable components, such as List, Title etc,etc. are self complete, these components should not understand store data structure. Use properties instead of setState for display data.

(3) Do you really want the store to hold different type of data, or does the data belong to a different store.

(4) If the store must hold different type of data, my preference is not to "filter" by action type. Update all the view components listening to the store for simplicity.

Comment: Updating them all is fine, but my question is how to do this using Reflux. Do I pick out the relevant state data using [Reflux.connectFilter](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs#using-refluxconnectfilter) (as in my second example)

Comment: Yes one can definitely use Reflux.connectFilter, or one could implement custom getter/filter in the store.